# Java - Saving a text based adventure game

Tags: java, save

So i'm fairly new to coding in Java, I have a good amount of experience with C# and I know that they are very similar. I'm currently messing around with java by creating a text adventure game, the game uses cases (case 1, case 2, default etc.), and currently i'm working on a saving and loading feature but i don't exactly know how i would go about saving a branching game that uses cases to further the coding, does anyone have any ideas as how to do this?

Comment: The question is not clear to me.

Comment: @c0der that why did you respond to the question

Comment: In hope you make it clear. Maybe the huge number of answers suggest that I am not the only one.

Comment: @c0der What about the question do you find unclear?

Comment: " how i would go about saving a branching game that uses cases to further the coding"  - maybe an [MCVE] example of what exactly are you trying to save and retrieve ?

Comment: @c0der alright let me see if I can explaine better. Im creating a branching text adventure game, to make it branch the code takes in input from the player, the code than gives that input to a case statement (case 1, case 2, case 3) withing that case there are more options for the player and another case statment, this provides the branching for the game. The exact question is that Im trying to create a save function that will save the exact position withing the cases so when the player opens up the game again, it will bring the to the spot that they left of at withing the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Maintain a data object, a hashmap with key-value pairings should be good for this which keeps track of all relevant states. Every time a case happens, the associated value for that key is updated. When they select save, you export the hash map to an text file in any format you desire, as long as it's a key value pairing such as xml. You just load that same file into your hashmap and that will initialize your game to the state where it was left off.

Comment: Im not 100% familiar with hashmaps, especially using it with cases, could you give me a quick example of how this would work with a single case

Answer (score 0):

To combine what I gt from your explanation and @JodanGS answer, here is a basic, commented demonstration of storing different "user dependent" variables into a hashmap:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StoreCase {

    private static Map<String, String> casesMap = new HashMap<>();
    private static final String CASE1 = "case1";
    private static final String CASE2 = "case2";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        System.out.println("Which  case ? (1 or 2)");

        //initialize map
        casesMap.put(CASE1, null);
        casesMap.put(CASE2, null);

        //select case : get user input
        String s = null; boolean loop = true;
        int case1State = 0;

        while (loop ) {

            s= input.nextLine();

            try {

                case1State = Integer.parseInt(s);

            }catch (NumberFormatException ex) {}

            switch (case1State) {

                case 1:
                    //store case in map
                    casesMap.put(CASE1, String.valueOf(case1State));
                    //stop loop flag
                    loop = false;
                    //do something
                    break;

                case 2:
                    //store case in map
                    casesMap.put(CASE2, String.valueOf(case1State));
                    //stop loop flag
                    loop = false;
                    //do something
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Not valid. Try again.");
            }
        }

        //print map
        for(String key : casesMap.keySet()) {

            System.out.println(" case "+ key  +" state "+ casesMap.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you find it useful.